# lvalue error in nested if statement

Tags: c++

This program is for a class and I'm simply trying to input data from a file and use that data to do some calculations. The program outputs each data set through multiple data sets. The output also increments the number of which data set is being output. It ends up in a table with the "test" number on the left side. I'm trying to pause the loop at every 10 data sets and prompt the user to press 'enter' to continue reviewing the data sets. I am using a nested if statement to do this but my compiler comes back with an error and I don't know why. Here is the code for the loop. I have initialized 'testNum' at 0 before the loop.

```
while(carFile)
    {
       milesPG = miles / gallons;
       testNum = testNum + 1;
       totalAllTestMPG = totalAllTestMPG + milesPG;
       totalAllGal = totalAllGal + gallons;
       totalAllMiles = totalAllMiles + miles;
       cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
       cout << setw(3) << testNum;
       cout << setw(9) << gallons;
       cout << setw(9) << miles;
       cout << setw(7) << milesPG << endl;
       carFile >> gallons >> miles;
            if(testNum % 10 = 0)           // <---error occurs here 
              {
                cout << "Press enter to continue.";
                getline (cin, proceed);
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(testNum % 10 = 0)
```

should be

```
if(testNum % 10 == 0)
```

`=` is the assignment operator, while `==` is the equality operator.

The error is because `testNum % 10` is an rvalue, while the (incorrect) assignment requires an lvalue as left operand.